# How do I avoid assigning an owner/security relationship to a node when creating it in a structr custom method?

Tags: structr

I've written a structr custom method for a type (Person). The method is makeNewHire and it takes an existing person and creates a bunch of ToDos for them which it then attaches to them.

In the course of doing so, it creates 2 relationships between the structr User type I'm logged in as, and each new ToDo node. The relationships are of the types :SECURITY and :OWNS.

Now, when I try to update the status of the todo as the person to whom they're assigned (not the admin who creates the new nodes), I get a 401 error. I think it's because of the security settings I inadvertently created.

How can I use a structr custom method, accessible via the rest api, to create new nodes without creating those relationships? Eventually I want to make it so only admins and people with specific relationships to the todos can change them, so if you can point me towards a tutorial about this stuff, that would be great too.

Here's the relevant code in my method. It's using server side JS:

```
for(i=0;i<tasks.length;i++) {
   newTD = Structr.create('ToDo', 'title', tasks[i].todo.title, 'marker', 'delete me2', 'event', 'First Day');
   Structr.create_relationship(newTD, thisPerson, 'ASSIGNED_TO');
   Structr.create_relationship(newTD, thisGeneralist, 'ASSIGNED_BY');
   // go through the documents and attach them.
   for(j=0;j<tasks[i].taskDocs.length; j++) {
      Structr.create_relationship(newTD, tasks[i].taskDocs[j], 'HAS_DOCUMENT');
  }
}
```

Comment: Normally, you don't need to create relationships on your own. Structr does that for you when you modify the "remote attribute".

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the 401 error if you create a resource access grant in the Security section for the matching URL signature, see https://support.structr.com/article/235.

Answer (score 0):

Axel is correct, but I want to identify what I did that caused me not to be able to use his fix.

I had created the ToDos in Structr, and Structr had assigned them SECURITY and OWNS relationships with other nodes. I'd deleted those relationships and as a consequence couldn't properly interact with them.